# How to save settings in wince

Tags: memory, windows-ce

I have a chinese radio with wince 6 and i'm getting an error related to memory. I entered into windows to increase memory cursor but after I restart the cursor i still in same position. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The memory slider to set storage and program memory is hard coded into any WINCE image: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sloh/2004/09/09/ce-memory-division-between-storage-program-memory/

**If your device has an hard drive and your wince registry is persisted**, the easiest way to manage the slider is to write a program to be executed at startup that will set your desired value by calling SetSystemMemoryDivision(). You can hard code your desired value into your program or use a configuration file or use the wince registry.
For example: http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/set-memory-division

You then have to deploy your program into your wince hard drive and modify the registry to tell wince to execute your program at startup.

Hope this helps